# Knockout DataTables Row Click After fetch data

Tags: knockout.js, datatables, knockout-mvc

I have a view model that is bound to a modal popup via knockout. The modal has a button that fetches data (ajax from the server in reality but just from some static code for this example) then binds that data to a table and converts it to a DataTable. Knockout adds the DataTable.

The data gets fetched and the data table is rendered correctly. However, I need the ability to select rows by clicking on them and it seems like those databind statements aren't getting processed after fetching the data.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: initArray">Init Table</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: swapArray">Swap Table Array</a>
<div id="datatablescontainer" style="border: 1px solid green;"></div>

<div id="datatableshidden" style="display:none;" >
    <table class="datatable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>first</th>
          <th>last</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>            
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
            <tr data-bind="click: $parent.testAlert">
                <td align="center" data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
          <td align="center" data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.rows = ko.observable(null);
    this.datatableinstance = null;
    
    this.initArray = function() {
            var rowsource1 =  [   
                    new ChildVM({ "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Smith"}),
                    new ChildVM({ "firstName" : "Mary", "lastName" : "Smith" })
                  ];         
        this.redraw(rowsource1);

    }

    this.swapArray = function() {
      var rowsource2 =  [   
                      new ChildVM({ "firstName" : "James", "lastName" : "Smith" }),
                      new ChildVM({ "firstName" : "Alice", "lastName" : "Smith" }),
                      new ChildVM({ "firstName" : "Doug", "lastName" : "Smith" })
                    ];       
        this.redraw(rowsource2);
    }

    this.redraw = function(rowsource) {
      this.rows(rowsource);


      var options = { paging: false, "order": [[0, "desc"]], "searching":true };
      var datatablescontainer = $('#datatablescontainer');
      var html = $('#datatableshidden').html();

      //Destroy datatable
      if (this.datatableinstance) {
        this.datatableinstance.destroy();
        datatablescontainer.empty();
      }

      //Recreate datatable
      datatablescontainer.html(html);
      this.datatableinstance = datatablescontainer.find('table.datatable').DataTable(options);    
    }
    
   this.testAlert = function() {
        alert('test');
    }
    
};
 
var ChildVM = function(data) {
    var self = this;
  if(data != null)
  {
    self.firstName = data.firstName;
    self.lastName = data.lastName;
  }
  
  this.testAlert = function() {
        alert('test');
    }
}
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Here is a fiddle (customized from another post for this issue).

*Updating fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/websitewill/rgsw2odp/17/

I have testClick on the main VM and on ChildVM. I've tried with $parent.testClick and just testClick in the table row databind. Neither are called (but no errors reported either).

Thanks for any help.
Will

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Looks like calling cleanNode before applyBindings after loading the new results and creating the DataTable does the trick.Like this.

```
ko.cleanNode(dataTableContainer.find('table.definitions-datatable')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(this, dataTableContainer.find('table.definitions-datatable')[0]);
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/websitewill/rgsw2odp/35/

Thanks,
Will